Upper triangular matrices conjugate transpose
Let $R$ be an upper triangular matrix. $R^{*}$ be the conjugate transpose of $R$. If $R^{*}R$ is diagonal then R is diagonal. How will I prove this?
My attempt:
I could prove $r_{11}=1$ and $r_{1k}=0$ in he first row so first row of $R$ should be 0 by writing $R^{*}$ as lower triangular matrix.However I could not make progress.What can be the general idea?
Thank you in advance.

You have the right idea, and you can usually proceed arguments like this by induction on the dimension of the matrix. If $R$ is an $n\times n$ upper triangular, then you can write it as
$$ R = \left( \begin{array}{cc} r_{11} & r_{1-} \\ 0 & P \end{array} \right) $$
Here, $P$ is an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ upper triangular. The adjoint is then
$$ R^* = \left( \begin{array}{cc} {r_{11}}^* & 0 \\ {r_{1-}}^* & P^* \end{array} \right) $$
Then, you can use your argument verbatim to show that $r_{11}=1$ and $r_{1-}=0$.  Finally, if $R^*R$ is diagonal and $r_{1-}=0$ then $P*P$ must also be diagonal, and applying the induction hypothesis will get you where you need to be.
